# Using a T::Type typedef for defaulting template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Comparator = std::less<typename T::Key>>
struct Container
{
    std::map<typename T::Key, T*, Comparator> m;
};
```

This is the problem part: `typename Comparator = std::less<typename T::Key>`

i.e. have a typedef within the implementation of the T be used for the specialization of the comparator. Is it always necessary that the thing that the comparator uses (T::Key) be specified as an explicit parameter to the template?

I realize there are other ways around this by changing the T class, (e.g. require an explicit T::compareKey method), but the question is more around whether template syntax can be used to achieve something like this.

Comment: Why don't you compile it first?

Comment: error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'Key'

Comment: @idij - On what line, using which compiler, and what headers have you included? :-) Seems ok in isolation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that's valid, as long as all the necessary definitions are available when the template is instantiated, and it certainly [works for me.](http://ideone.com/XWu3I)

Are you including `<map>`? It's possible that you might also need to include `<functional>` for `std::less`, although I'm sure that must be included by `<map>`.

Does your compiler support C++11, and have you enabled that support? Older compilers (or those configured for strict C++03 compliance) will get confused by your use of `>>` to close two template parameter lists; they will interpret it as the right-shift operator. In that case, you can fix the problem by adding a space between them.

If neither of these are the problem, please include a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem, the exact error message with an indication of which code lines it refers to, and let us know which compiler you're using.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for confirming it's valid. I have figured out the problem, was in a macro that was tying all that together in the real implementation. The macro had a friend class Container line before the definition of the Key typedef.